# How do I delay a form from submitting

Tags: jquery

I have an additional function to execute before I submit the form. This isn't doing the trick.

```
$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');
    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout( function () { 
        $(this).submit();
    }, 300);

});
```

This isn't working obviously.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to fire the event on the form element itself, not on a jQuery selection. (In fact, you weren't even selecting the form element – inside `setTimeout`, `this` is the global object.)

Cache a reference to the form (`this`) and call its `submit` method:

```
$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = this.id,
        form = this;
    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();

    setTimeout( function () { 
        form.submit();
    }, 300);
});
```

Note that I have also replaced your inefficient `$(this).attr('id')` call with `this.id`.  Note also that you have to call the DOM form element's submit method, not the jQuery method, so that the jQuery event handler is not triggered, which would cause an infinite (and totally ineffectual) loop.

Comment: I've tried this, but FireBug says form.submit() is not a function. I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.

Comment: Ya, I can get it to work in JSFiddle, but not on my page. I'm loading jQuery dynamically, so it's might be related to that. hrmm

Comment: "Submit is not a function" was because my submit button was named submit. Changing the name of the button fixed. This works perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: How to make this work when we have two or more submit buttons with different values ? e.preventDefault() will loose the selected value.

Comment: @mcoenca You could insert a hidden form element with the desired name and value.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = this.id,
              $this = $(this);

    mySpecialFunction(formId);

    event.preventDefault();
    $this.unbind("submit");
    setTimeout( $.proxy( $.fn.submit, $this ), 300);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set a callback in your function

```
$('form').submit( function(event) {
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');

    mySpecialFunction(formId, $(this).doWhatever(formId );

    event.preventDefault();
});

function mySpecialFunction(id, onComplete) {

    if ($.isFunction(onComplete)) {
        onComplete.call(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also possible with the jquery delay method:

```
$(function() {
    $('#the_form').delay(300).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to unbind the submit event, and within the setTimeout refer to the proper "this" instead of the window.

```
$(this).unbind("submit");
var self = this;
setTimeout( function () { 
  $(self).submit();
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the submit event is called over and over again, but is preventing the submission because of preventDefault. Either unbind the submit event after your function has been executed, or use a boolean value to set and check if it has been already executed.

Answer (score 0):

another small code to delay form submit as follows

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds

    $("<p>Delay...</p>").appendTo("body");
});
```